# InvalidCertificate error running the cardano-node (v 1.35.7) static binary

Tags: cardano-node

I'm trying to run the cardano-node static binary with the following command:

```
cardano-node run \
  --topology environments/topology.json \
  --database-path db \
  --socket-path ipc/node.socket \
  --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
  --port 3001 
  --config environments/config.json
```

But no matter the configuration options, it's always shutting down with the following error:

```
[Framey:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2023-04-12 08:39:37.16 UTC] Started opening Volatile DB
[Framey:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2023-04-12 08:39:37.16 UTC] Opened vol db
[Framey:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2023-04-12 08:39:37.16 UTC] Started opening Ledger DB
[Framey:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2023-04-12 08:39:37.16 UTC] Replaying ledger from genesis
[Framey:cardano.node.ChainDB:Info:5] [2023-04-12 08:39:37.16 UTC] Closed Immutable DB.
[Framey:cardano.node:Critical:5] [2023-04-12 08:39:37.16 UTC] fromList [("error",String "could not create initial ChainValidationState: InvalidCertificate\nCallStack (from HasCallStack):\n  error, called at src/Ouroboros/Consensus/Byron/Ledger/Ledger.hs:133:19 in ouroboros-consensus-byron-0.1.0.1-A6Uz6cpocu3BICcYhLnc6M:Ouroboros.Consensus.Byron.Ledger.Ledger"),("kind",String "ConsensusStartupException")]

Shutting down..

cardano-node: could not create initial ChainValidationState: InvalidCertificate
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Ouroboros/Consensus/Byron/Ledger/Ledger.hs:133:19 in ouroboros-consensus-byron-0.1.0.1-A6Uz6cpocu3BICcYhLnc6M:Ouroboros.Consensus.Byron.Ledger.Ledger
```

What does this mean? And more importantly, how can it be fixed?

I'm using the latest binary (1.35.7) with the preview network configs on Linux (Ubuntu 22.04).

**UPDATE**:
It seems to be a bug in the tarball binary distribution: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/5076

**UPDATE 2**:
Bug confirmed. 1.35.6 does work as expected.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Its unlikely to run in less that 16G.

Comment: I've got 64 GB of ram, so that's definitely not the issue. I run nodes using docker, sometimes two or three together.