# Chain error when attempting to start cardano-node

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

I try to start `cardano-node` with the following command

```
./cardano-node run \
    --topology testnet/topology.json \
    --database-path testnet/db/ \
    --socket-path testnet/db/node.socket \
    --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
    --port 1337 \
    --config testnet/config.json
```

However I get the following error:

```
[workstat:cardano.node:Critical:5] [2023-04-19 19:48:24.04 UTC] fromList [("error",String "could not create initial ChainValidationState: InvalidCertificate\nCallStack (from HasCallStack):\n  error, called at src/Ouroboros/Consensus/Byron/Ledger/Ledger.hs:133:19 in ouroboros-consensus-byron-0.1.0.1-A6Uz6cpocu3BICcYhLnc6M:Ouroboros.Consensus.Byron.Ledger.Ledger"),("kind",String "ConsensusStartupException")]
```

What's happening?

Comment: Check this out. Appears to be a bug. https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/11032/invalidcertificate-error-running-the-cardano-node-v-1-35-7-static-binary